# Can we group two instances/snapshots under some folder in AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

I've created two different instances in AWS EC2 which are used for single purpose (SFTP) . I wanted to group/store these two instances(ex: under one single folder,may be) so that in future I'll get to know these two instances are be used for SFTP purpose.

Comment: Use tags. While it wont really be organized in a folder, it can be searched by.

Comment: Can you please let me know when we create a tag, how can we search using it. I tried creating tag, but didn't understand how to search the resources using that tag.

Comment: I got to know how to search it :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As datasage mentioned we can use tags. In order to search for resources under a tag, go to "Tag Editor" under AWS. Provide details like Key name that you used while creating a tag and it will display you all the resources that you've tagged.